# VBA to loop through multiple sheets in a workbook to populate values referencing a list for specific Sheet name

Tags: vba

I have multiple sheets (over 500+) in a workbook.  On each sheet, I need to track data. More than often, 100+ sheets will have the same data values.  I am looking to utilize a VBA script to loop through a list of sheet names (using an external source like a csv file) and auto populating the fields on the sheets listed in the csv file.

I've done a macro recording of the inputs I need to fill on each sheet:

```
Sub Fill01()
'
' Fill01 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MM/DD/YYYY"
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Engineer_Name"
    Range("I7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("I21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a worksheet called, say, 'ListOfSheets' to your workbook (with lots of sheets to edit). Type the names of the sheets you want to be updated in a column starting from a1; this is your list (instead of a CSV file you mentioned; a CSV file is also ok but it takes a few more steps).
Then switch to the VBA editor, insert a new module and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoIt()
   Dim rngeItem As Variant
   For Each rngeItem In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ListOfsheets").UsedRange.Cells
       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(rngeItem))
           Debug.Print .Name
           ' Do what you want to do with this worksheet
             .Range("B7") = "MM/DD/YYYY"
             .Range("C7") = "Engineer_Name"
             .Range("I7") = "0"
             .Range("I9") = "0"
             .Range("I11") = "0"
             .Range("I13") = "0"
             .Range("I15") = "0"
             .Range("I17") = "0"
             .Range("I19") = "0"
             .Range("I21") = "0"
             '...
             ' Do whatever else
             '...
       End With
   Next rngeItem
   
End Sub
```

and run.
You don't have to 'select` (cells or ranges) to perform actions/set their values; it is much faster to do it without selecting or activating (as I provided). I don't know why you used the FormulaR1C1 property; you are setting values, not formulae.

Comment: I haven't tested yet but just by looking at it.. That makes sense to create another sheet in the workbook called "ListOfSheets".  That's thinking outside of the box for sure..  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Type the following macro code into a new module sheet.

```
  Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I see.. let me try.  Appreciate the quick response

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I am not looking to loop through all the sheets. Only particular sheets need to be filled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761697/for-each-function-to-loop-through-specifically-named-worksheets